# android, issue with notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android

I have a problem. there is one view containing `ListView` on it. it's content is dynamically updated. i try to move this view using view.layout(...) method. it moves good and stands at position i want. but when `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called on `ListView`, my view returns to it's previous position and it is a problem for me. i know, that `notifyDataSetChanged()` rebuilds all reflecting views. so, please give me a piece of advice to solve this problem

Comment: please provide some code.......and notifyDataSetChanged() is called on Adapter not listView

Comment: And to move your view you should use Android Animations.